# Valid std::search use to find all occurences of a subsequence (avoid infinite loop)

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to find *all* occurences of a subsequence within a sequence. My idea is to use `std::search` and then advance the resulting iterator until I reach the end of the collection.

This is the code that works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<int> MainSequence {2,3,1,2,3,4,-5,8,2,4,3,2,3,6,2,3,2,3};
    //for the sake of simplicity assume MainSequence is always non-empty

    vector<int> SubSequence {2,3}; // this will always be of length 2
    auto it = MainSequence.begin();
    int Count = 0;
  
    while (it < MainSequence.end() - 1)
    {
        it = search(it, MainSequence.end(), SubSequence.begin(),SubSequence.end()) + 2;
        Count++;
    }
    
    // Count = 5   

    return 0;

}
```

I've tested various combinations and it seems to work, but I have a feeling I've done to much tweaking for something like this to work.

Can you help me understand why will this `while` loop become infinite if:

- the condition is changed to `it < MainSequence.end()` or `it != MainSequence.end()`?

and/or

- in the loop body, if `it` is incremented by `1` instead by `2`?

Many thanks!

Comment: to decide if you increment *it* by 1 or 2 it is needed to know what is the expected result searching  `{1, 1}` in `{1,1,1,1}`, if you want 2 then add 2, if you want 3 add 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the condition is changed to it < MainSequence.end() or it != MainSequence.end()

both are right, personally I prefer the second way

but for sure `(it < MainSequence.end() - 1)` can be never true and yo have to use one of the two proposal above

> in the loop body, if it is incremented by 1 instead by 2?

To decide it is needed to know what is the expected result searching  `{1, 1}` in `{1,1,1,1}`, if you want 2 then add 2, if you want 3 add 1

Warning doing `Count++;` unconditionally the result will be 1 even *SubSequence* is not in *MainSequence*

For instance do

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<int> MainSequence {2,3,1,2,3,4,-5,8,2,4,3,2,3,6,2,3,2,3};
    //for the sake of simplicity assume MainSequence is always non-empty

    vector<int> SubSequence {2,3}; // this will always be of length 2
    auto it = MainSequence.begin();
    int Count = 0;
  
    while ((it = search(it, MainSequence.end(), SubSequence.begin(),SubSequence.end()))
           != MainSequence.end())
    {
      it += SubSequence.size(); // or += 1 depending on what you expect searching  {1, 1} in {1,1,1,1}
      Count++;
    }
    
    cout << Count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
5
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: I know that they are both right in _theory_ but if I do any of those changes, I end up with an infinite loop for the example I provided.

Comment: If you increment it by 2 it's possible you could iterate past the end of the vector

Comment: @Tharwen no because the increment is done only in case the subsequence is found and its size is 2, so in the worst case it+2 is end.

Answer (score 2):

More generic way would be:

```
std::size_t count_subsequence(const std::vector<T>& mainSequence, const std::vector<T>& subSequence)
{
    assert(!subSequence.empty());
    std::size_t count = 0;
    auto it = mainSequence.begin();
    while (it != mainSequence.end())
    {
        it = search(it, mainSequence.end(), subSequence.begin(), subSequence.end());
        if (it != mainSequence.end()) {
             count++;
             std::advance(it, subSequence.size()); // or 1 depending how you want to count {1, 1} in {1, 1, 1, 1}
        } 
    }
    return count;
}
```

`std::search(..) + 2` invokes undefined behavior when not found (`end() + 2`)

> Can you help me understand why will this while loop become infinite if:

> the condition is changed to `it < MainSequence.end()`
> or `it != MainSequence.end()`?

because you increment by more than one you have to ensure you have a valid iterator and not iterator such as `MainSequence.end() + 1`
in the loop body, if it is incremented by 1 instead by 2?

Comment: sorry to say but why doubling both the search and the compare with end() ? Also if you found the subseq it is safe to incr iterator with subseq size ;-)

Comment: I prefer to initialize count to `0` instead of `-1`. we increment `it` only when valid. we handle empty `mainSequence` vector, We might avoid first `search` by increasing count in the `if`part.

Comment: I do not understand you, you do not need to initialize count with -1 writing only one time the search and compare with end, did you see my answer ?

Comment: For personal style, I avoid infinite loop to iterate, (your first version before edit), and I avoid mixing comparison with assignment in same statement.